# how to use asp.net repeater with list of dictionary?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dictionary

i have a list of dictionary, i create it like this :

```
List<Dictionary<String, String>> _list = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
            var q = from d in db.TT_DELIVERies
                    where d.DeliveryOrderNumber == donumber
                    select new { d.DeliveryId };
            if (q.Count() > 0)
            {
                var qd = from d in db.TT_DELIVERY_REQUESTs
                         where d.DeliveryOrderId == q.ToList()[0].DeliveryId
                         select new { d.ItemDescription, d.PackageDescription };

                Console.Write(qd.Count());
                if (qd.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var r in qd)
                    {
                        Dictionary<String, String> temp = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                        temp.Add("Name", r.ItemDescription);
                        temp.Add("Desc", r.PackageDescription);
                        _list.Add(temp);
                    }
                }
            }
```

i try to bind with repeater like this :

```
rptAddedDocs.DataSource = _list;
                rptAddedDocs.DataBind();
```

and this is my repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptAddedDocs" runat="server">

                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <table id="tblListAddedDocs" class="table table-condensed table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>No</th>
                                    <th>Document Name</th>
                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                    <th>UOM</th>
                                    <th>Description</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            </HeaderTemplate>

                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td><%# Eval("Name")%> </td>
                                    <td>1 </td>
                                    <td>Envlope </td>
                                    <td><%#Eval("Desc")%> </td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </ItemTemplate>

                            <FooterTemplate>
                                </table>
                            </FooterTemplate>

                        </asp:Repeater>
```

but i get error like this :

```
DataBinding: 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'.
```

please help me how to use repeater with list  of dictionary correctly?

Answer (score 1):

In your .aspx file you should write this:

```
<%#((System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>)Container.DataItem)["Name"]%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confusing the purpose of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. A dictionary is a data structure used to store key/value pairs, where keys are unique. The first property of the `Dictionary.Add()` method is this key, not an arbitrary name for the data in the second parameter. If you chose to keep your existing data structure, you don't actually need a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`, but a simple `Dictionary<string, string>` from the looks of things, and you would need to bind your data on "Key" and "Value".

It looks like what you're *actually* trying to do is create a list of a type which doesn't exist, one with a `string` property named `Name` and another named `Desc`. The easiest thing to do is to create your own class with exactly this definition:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

Then declare your `_list` variable as an instance of `List<MyItem>`, and change your population in the `foreach` loop to

```
_list.Add(new MyItem
{
    Name = r.ItemDescription;
    Desc = r.PackageDescription;
});
```